# PyQt, Don't change qtablewidgetitem font during editing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I tried change QTableWidgetItem font, and complete that.

But, In Editmode, not change font.

(PS. I shouldn't give same style, so i don't use qss style sheet)

Below code, If Input F1 key, Size up current cell font size.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_main()
        self.init_table()        
        self.resize(500,500)
        self.show()
        
    def init_main(self):
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        
    def init_table(self):
        self.table = QTableWidget(5, 5, self)
        self.table.resize(500, 500)
        # init QTableWidgetItem in QTableWidget (5 x 5),
        [[self.table.setItem(row, col,QTableWidgetItem("text")) for row in range(5)] for col in range(5)]
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        # If input F1, resize font-size in current item.
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_F1:
            cur = self.table.currentItem()
            font = cur.font()
            font.setPointSize(30)
            cur.setFont(font)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the font on an item just changes the font for that item, not for its *editor*.

What you need to do is to create an item delegate (which is an object that is responsible of *showing* items and provide interaction with the underlying model, including the appropriate editor).

Since setting the font on a QTableWidgetItem equals to set the `Qt.FontRole` of the index, you can easily access that from the [`createEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) function, call the base implementation to get the editor that is going to be returned, and apply the font to it if a font is set.

```
class FontDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, opt, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, opt, index)
        font = index.data(Qt.FontRole)
        if font is not None:
            editor.setFont(font)
        return editor

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def init_table(self):
        self.table = QTableWidget(5, 5)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.table)
        [[self.table.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem("text")) for row in range(5)] for col in range(5)]
        self.table.setItemDelegate(FontDelegate(self.table))
    # ...
```

<sub>Unrelated note: the table should be added to the layout (as I did in the above code), and not just created as a child of the main window.</sub>

Comment: Thank you it works. but not real time... how to solve that..?

Comment: What do you mean by "but not real time"?

Comment: It means... not immediately.  (sry, i can't english)

Comment: Please find a way to explain yourself.

Comment: To see the result, i change current cell. I think reason, i used "table.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.CurrentChanged)"

Comment: The reason for using editmode is "First Korean Input is blocked"

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to change the font also during editing?

Comment: yes, I always use edit mode, not select. so i want to change the font during editing.